# Setup Python variable environment on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu-10.04

how to set or create new environment variables in ubuntu(10.04, 64bits), for a python library. I have to configure

PYTHONPATH

library_HOME

library_data

Comment: can you be more specific on what you are trying to achieve? Setting environment variables only for the library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, you can use `export`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/library
export library_HOME=/path/to/library_HOME
etc.
```

You can put these lines in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile to have them loaded every time you start a login shell.